# Android Emulator on ARM: system images

Tags: android, android-emulator

In it's latest release, Android Emulator can be built for ARM64 hosts:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#emulator_for_arm64_hosts

Unfortunately, there aren't any new Android system images for ARM64. Latest one that I can see in the Android Virtual Device Manager is Nougat (API 25).

Does anyone know if there are any newer ARM64 Android system images for the emulator?

I've also tried building my own from AOSP, but without success...

Comment: Why do you need emulator ARM images? They have been deprecated for performance reasons long time ago.

Comment: To run them on an ARM host.

Comment: Have you checked here if there is something useful? https://source.android.com/setup/build/gsi

Comment: I've tried one of the GSI images that I've downloaded from their CI systems but it just didn't run. The problem that I see is that besides the system.img you also need other files (like ramdisk.img, kernel-ranchu, userdata.img etc.) to run the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Found these links
New ARM system images has been released for the upcoming android version:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/arm64-v8a-S_r01.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a-S_r01-linux.zip

from this thread in github
https://github.com/google/android-emulator-container-scripts/issues/192

was not successful in building emulator using them.
So ended up running emulator in docker on arm.