# I created an Android virtual environment with CPU/ABI arm64-v8a through the AVD manager built into Android Studio, but an error is occurring

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I created an Android 12 virtual environment with CPU/ABI arm64-v8a through the AVD manager built into Android Studio, but an error is occurring.

[Error Image is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RROc.png)

I'm using an Intel CPU MacBook.

If I selected CPU/ABI as x86 or armeabi-v7a when creating the emulator, it works without any problem.

I also checked that the SDK for the Android version to be created is installed.

What's the problem?

Comment: See: [Android Emulator on ARM: system images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63594734/295004)

Comment: Are you successful?
The link you provided doesn't seem to have anything to do with the solution.

Comment: You selected a `ARM64` image which is for ARM64 Host CPUs.

Comment: Can't run arm64 emulator on x86 macbook? If so, why does it work when the CPU/ABI is arm and not arm64?

Answer (score 0):

From: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210099270#comment2

> the arm64 images on api28-31 are meant for M1 host.

Historically emulator ABI meant what architecture the emulator 'natively' supported, i.e. binaries generated by NDK.

- armeabi
- armeabi-7a

Ran on older QEMU virtualization which did the ARM to x86 translation. When the emulator was released it had no graphics hardware acceleration so was laggy but operational.

- x86
- x86-64

Is for modern hardware and support virtualization, and have reasonable performance.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#extensions

Google added ARM ABI support to x86/x86-64 emulator images for certain version of Android:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#30-0-0

as mentioned in the above issue ticket link:

> If you need to test arm abis on x86_64 host you can use the api 31/30/28, as they have ndk-translated arm support.